# Screen tearing in Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: tearing

I have really bad screen tearing in pretty much everything including playing games, moving windows around, watching videos... What should I do to fix this screen tearing?

Comment: Which GPU do you have and which graphics driver are you using?

Comment: @Android Dev GTX 960, Nvidia 375.26 driver

Answer (score 2):

Try going to **System Settings => Display and Monitor => Compositor**, and set Tearing Prevention ("vsync") to **Full Screen Repaints**

Comment: I already tried that. It made it a tiny bit better, but not much